# Admin SDK has to be enabled on every new copy

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google sheets document/template that gets copied for each new project.  In the google sheets I have a script that requires the admin SDK enabled as it looks at the user profile and the admin directory. Every time I copy the google sheet, the admin SDK needs to be re-enabled.  Is there a way around this?  Or is it possible to script this in?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't. The only workaround I can imagine is to setup your own independent app that communicate with your script and handle the API calls.  This could work but I admit it is a bit complicated and probably slower...

Comment: Distribute your script as an add-on in your domain. Then it only needs to be activated (and not authorized) in each Google Sheets file. Further, all the sheets will use the same Google Cloud Project, so you can better monitor quota usage, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google docs scripts asks for permission everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36445923/google-docs-scripts-asks-for-permission-everytime)

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks! I'll look into implementing that.