# How to ask for user permission from a Spreadsheet for filebound script?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, google-apps-script, google-apps

I have a simple Google Spreadsheet with some code behind - that is, my script is bound to the Spreadsheet file (no standalone code, neither code deployed as add-on). When an user edits one given column, the scripts runs an email check (that is, it compares the current user email with the one saved on the table). The code is as follows:

```
function showDialog() {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Apenas o usuário que registrou a emissão da passagem pode realizar alterações em seu registro!<br><input type=\"button\" value=\"Fechar\" onclick=\"google.script.host.close()\" />")
    .setWidth(400)
    .setHeight(90);
    ui.showModalDialog(html, 'Edição não permitida!');
}

function onEdit(e){
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var this_file = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/key_to_my_file/edit');
    var main_sheet = this_file.getSheetByName("Tickets");  
    var edited_range = e.range;  
    var edited_row = edited_range.getRow();

    if(e.user != main_sheet.getRange("B"+edited_row).getValue()){
          edited_range.setValue(e.oldValue);
          showDialog();
    }
}
```

My issue is that, being the owner of the script, I have granted it all the permissions it needs - therefore, my dialog is shown properly either via the Script Editor or the Spreadsheet itself, editing data I'm not allowed by the script rules to edit.

When it comes to other users, though, it doesn't work. I can't see any error in the execution logs for the OnEdit trigger I have, nothing. If the user, then, opens the Script Editor, runs the function `showDialog`, grants the permissions in the following box, it all starts to work.

I can't expect, though, that non technical users will be able to do all that. I need a way to either be able to follow those steps. Also, I have to use a custom dialog, rather than the usual ui.alert() (which works finely, by the way, no permissions issues), because I need a non-blocking alert.

I'm basing my comprehension on this matter on [google apps script docs page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs), in particular the session "Custom sidebars".

How can I either get rid of the need for permissions, or force the user of my spreadsheet to grant them from start?

Comment: I think only users who have permission to edit a container can run its bound script. Collaborators who have only view access cannot open the script editor, although if they make a copy of the parent file, they become the owner of the copy and will be able to see and run a copy of the script. So you will need permission to perform this. But there's a possible solution for this, you can publish your script as Google document add-on. Please check this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36445923/google-docs-scripts-asks-for-permission-everytime).

Comment: "only users who have permission to edit a container"
But my users have the permission to edit it, I just don't expect them to know how to. All of my collaborators have edit permissions on the table :( 
Gonna look into that post, though.